# Replace single object in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I`m filtering a DataFrame from a .CSV using Jupyter Notebook that looks like this:

`+----------+-----------+------------+
| 0 Header1  |  Header2  |   Header3 |
| 1 Value 1  |  A        |      B    |
| 2 Value 1  |  A        |      B    |
| 3 Value 2  |  C        |      D    |
| 4 Value 1  |  A        |      B    |
| 5 Value 3  |  B        |      E    |
| 6 Value 3  |  B        |      E    |
| 7 Value 2  |  C        |      D    |
+----------+-----------+-------------+`

I want to replace some objets in each colum, for example, the letter "A" in "Header2" of "4 Value 1" and letter "B" and "E" from "6 Value 3".
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is reasoning/logic for you to replace the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional indexing. Your first example can be done like this:

```py
# Assuming the DataFrame is df

condition_one = df['0 Header 1'] == '4 Value 1'
condition_two = df['Header 2'] == 'A'
new_value = 'N'

df[condition_one & condition_two] = new_value
```